# alias subdomain to s3 bucket in route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I have an s3 bucket called **downloads.domain.com** with files for users to download (standard bucket, not configured as static website hosting).

I can map in route53 using CNAME:
**downloads.domain.com --> downloads.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com**

It works fine but when the user opens **downloads.domain.com/somefile** in the browser it changes to **downloads.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com/somefile** (because it's a CNAME) and that's not what I want, I want the user to see my domain in his browser.

I tried to set it up in route53 as ALIAS instead of CNAME but I get an error saying the alias value is invalid.

Anybody knows a way to solve it?

Comment: A CNAME will never cause the address bar to change.  S3 is sending a redirect response to the initial request, I suspect.  This might be related to the age of the bucket in its current region, so how long have you had this bucket? Which region is it in? Alias only works with web site hosting-enabled buckets. Is there a reason you aren't using that feature?

Comment: The bucket was created a few minutes before I tried to configure in route53. I don't use the static site hosting feature because I want to keep the files private, I want to allow users to download from my bucket only if they have a URL with a signed policy.

Comment: I didn't change anything and it works now. I guess a few hours wait is required when it' a new bucket. Thanks Michael

Comment: @DanBolofe FYI, setting a bucket to static site hosting does not mean the files will be public.

Comment: FYI - it does take a bit of time for a newly-created bucket, named in the downloads.domain.com format, to map to a CNAME you create in DNS. I imagine those mappings are ether propagated out at end of creation, or maybe generated automatically only after requests are made to it?